# Saving links with Pocket on Android browsers?

Tags: chrome-for-android, firefox-for-android

Should I have a bookmarklet of some sort that does that?  There doesn't appear to be a button to do that in Firefox mobile or for Google for Android which is strange since there's a Pocket App for Android, and that app doesn't appear to save bookmarks, so you're just kind of trapped with the links that you saved on your computer using pocket.

I also, don't see any browser extensions for it.

Comment: You use the "Share" functionality to share the web page to Pocket – which then will save it.

Comment: @Izzy Oh, so it adds it to your browser's share functionality?  You don't say...I never thought of that  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Though this is really @Izzy's answer here's what I found on my device on how to do this:

1. Click the Hamburger button.

   - [image: Click the Hamburger button]
2. Click the Share button.

   - [image: Clicking the share button]
3. Click the Pocket Button

   - [image: Click the pocket button]

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Not only with Pocket, but also with several other similar services like Nextcloud Bookmarks or Wallabag. Thanks for self-answering (and credits :)!